# Realtime Notification System

Tags: real-time

I want to implement my own realtime notification system (like facebook - when someone in my friends list comments on/likes my status, I'm notified about that)

I just want to know which technologies are best suited for such problem domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It used to be `AJAX`, then there is now `Comet`. Just then, there is also HTML5 `Web Sockets`.

But i guess what is prevalent to your situation at present may be solved by `Comet`.

Its called pushed notification.

AJAX can be used in a pull notification manner, i.e. browser periodically checks the server for updates. Comet is for push notification, i.e. server sends updates to the browser.

Web Sockets is only relevant in HTML 5 enabled browsers.

Comment: Yes man, I'm currently learning more about comet programming. The server side language of my choice is php. But people are skeptical about php's performance with comet. What are the ideal server side language(s) to use with comet?

also, I am not sure if all the browsers (including IE6) support HTML5. :)

Comment: Hey TriNitro, its hard to tell, i.e. it well depends on the nature of your updates? Are you reading from database, processing a list, and then reverting back the results? I guess when they tell you PHP isn't the "choice" language for comet, they mean other platforms have better capabilities, i.e. EJB from JavaEE.. Other than that i am not really aware if PHP has any such disadvantage.